# "Chartkick is not defined" in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have set up Chartkick according to docs (I believe), but I get

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Chartkick is not defined"
```

Any ideas? Are there any order of things, not right? It works well in development.

Comment: in production environment have you install gem?, you can type bundle install to install it

Comment: I assume you're using chartkick gem. Have you added the js files to application.js? https://github.com/ankane/chartkick#quick-start

Comment: Yes, Chartkick gem is installed in all environments. I am not sure what it means to add js files to application.js. Anyways in Chrome I see traces of this in "sources" and under "assets" so I suppose it is correct in application js. /*
 * Chartkick.js
 * Create beautiful charts with one line of JavaScript
 * https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.js
 * v3.1.1
 * MIT License
 */

(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object'

Comment: Do I need some code in the views or layout?

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 6 / Webpacker, run:

```
yarn add chartkick chart.js
```

And in app/javascript/packs/application.js, add:

```
require("chartkick") require("chart.js")
```

If you're not using webpacker then you should start. Research how it works cause it's pretty important.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. I use 5.2 so far.

Answer (score 0):

All of a sudden it started working. All I did was some housekeeping, removing unnecessary references in application.js, deleting an easy-autocomplete.js file and doing a rails assets:clobber, and rails assets:precompile ENV=production (once again), changing some orders in application.js according to the standard order when creating a new project. I may improve this answer after some more investigation. Strange.